# Render <apex:inputField> only when field exists on target org

Tags: dynamic-visualforce

Is there a way to conditionally render an `apex:inputField` only if the field exists on the running org?

I tried the following syntax but always ran into errors:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c['optionalField__c']}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!CustomObject__c['optionalField']}"  
   rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL($ObjectType.CustomObject__c.fields['optionalField__c']))}" />
```

Comment: as far as I know, you can't, inputfields are hard-bound to an sobject field which must exist in the org, else you will fail on saving.

You could potentially make workarounds with normal HTML, and javascript/css, combined with extension variables, but this is quite a hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find any solution for this but I think as per your requirement you should use `"FieldSets"` and use that `FieldSet` to render fields on you visualforce page.

Here you can find [FieldSet](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) information.

I am suggesting this to you because i am using this and rendering the input fields based on some condition and it is working fine.

Comment: How come that this doesn't work for the RecordType field?